# Proving the Cone is not a smooth surface.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

$C:(x,y,z):z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$  suppose it is a smooth  surface  meaning there exists a smooth parametrization

$ φ(u,v):U⊂R^2→C$ such that $φ(u,v)=(φ_1(u,v),φ_2(u,v),φ_3(u,v))$ such that $φ_3=\sqrt{φ_1^2+φ_2^2}$ being continuously differentiable at every point but it fails at the peak since the limit at the peak of the derivative fails to be unique because if i approximate it through different paths(curves) it will be different. (So which is the the derivative( i tried taking the jacobian but not helpfull) and what limit do i  take to continue mathematically  my proof ).?

Another approach similar. 
$C:(x,y,z):z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$  suppose it is a smooth  surface  meaning there exists a smooth parametrization

$ φ(u,v):U⊂R^2→C$  now consider the projectio $p:C \rightarrow R^2$. Now i know from a theorem $φ$ is diffeomorpishm also $p\circ φ$  is a diffeomorphism( havent proven why yet)  so its inverse is smooth so $φ\circ ((p\circ φ)^{-1}):R^2 
 \rightarrow  C |(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2} )$ is differentiable since both  are which is a contradiction

Comment: This will not help, but any developable surface patch, with the exception of a planar patch, has a singularity when extended. The cone is one instance of that, with the singularity the apex.

Comment: You could try this one: if it is a 2 dimensional manifold then it is locally expressible as the graph of $(x,y)$, $(x,z)$, or $(y,z)$ near the cone point. For example, if its locally expressible as $(x,f(x,z),z)$ then we know from the relation above that $z^2=\sqrt{x^2+f(x,z)^2}$ and thus that $f(x,z)=\sqrt{z^2-x^2}$. But $f(x,z)$ isn't smooth at the origin so this is not possible. The other cases are similar.